# Why does the Python ** operator behave differently on arrays and scalars

Tags: python

I don't understand the justification for the following behavior of the ** operator in Python.  This returns a float:

```
>>> 10**-1
0.1
```

And this returns integers:

```
>>> y=np.array([10,10,10])
>>> y
array([10, 10, 10])
>>> y**-1
array([0, 0, 0])
```

Why?!

The following works, but the above seems very wrong.

```
>>> y**-1.0
array([ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1])
```

Comment: Because numpy arrays overload the `__pow__` special method?

Comment: Why would it be "very wrong"? Unless you're doing something unusual where you need to distinguish between positive and negative floating-point zero, it seems like it doesn't matter whether you get a FP or integer one.

Comment: When I say "very wrong" I mean that it seems to violate what I thought was a basic principle: that one can operate on arrays the way one would on scalars and get consistent results.

Answer (score 4):

For efficiency, numpy arrays are restricted to a specified type, for example with yours:

```
>>> y=np.array([10,10,10])
>>> y.dtype
dtype('int64')
```

Because an int can't represent the fractional part, it's discarded. If you use a floating point array like this, the result is what you expected:

```
>>> y=np.array([10,10,10], dtype='float32')
>>> y.dtype
dtype('float32')
>>> y**-1
array([ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1], dtype=float32)
```

Also, if the list you pass in initially contains `float` types, the `dtype` will default to `float64`:

```
>>> y=np.array([10.0 ,10.0 ,10.0])
>>> y.dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> y**-1
array([ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1])
```

Answer (score 1):

numpy implements it S.T. **ANY** math involving two int results in an int .... at least thats been largely my experience